# Making a bootable image of linux Red Hat Ent Es for a VM

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualization, redhat

I have a old server running Red Hat that has some valuable apps installed. I would like to create a bootable image of the drive and install it in a VM on a newer server. i am trying to avoid reinstalling Red Hat the apps and data. Any useful links or advice would be greatly appreciated.(Not yet decided on the VM Software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the virtualization technology you plan on using, you could use a p2v solution. For opensource virtualization (kvm/qemu/xen), virt-p2v and clonezilla are pretty good

Answer (score 0):

VMware's VMConverter can be used to build a VM from the RH system and run in a full ESXi server or a small VMPlayer session on your desktop.  See http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/